# How to import an svg sprite file in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

All im looking to do is use an svg from a sprite file in gatsby but the docs arent very clear, Im stuck at just importing it at the moment, when i try importing the svg it gives me an error:

"svg-sprite-loader exception".

Or if I take the ../ path away I get
If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'images/sprite.svg' is installed.

Currently importing like this which it doesnt like:

```
import sprite from "../images/sprites.svg"
```

Standard html way

```
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="images/sprites.svg#potato"></use>
        </svg>
```

What gatsby tells you to do

```
         <svg viewBox={sprite.viewBox}>
          <use xlinkHref={sprite.potato} />
        </svg>
```

Gatsby config for the svg is

```
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite",
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader`,
      options: {
        /* SVG sprite loader options */
        pluginOptions: {
          /* SVG sprite loader plugin options */
        },
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader` and `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite` are trying to take over SVG loading. Drop `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite` if you intend to use `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader`.

For what it's worth, the instructions provided by `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader` are not provided by Gatsby—it is a community plugin. If you have issues with it you might consider filing an issue with [the project repo](https://github.com/stldo/gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader).

Comment: So i tried uninstalling both and trying each individually but unfortunately neither of them work - i just get:

svg-sprite-loader exception. 

module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "static/sprite-870b25011c39c0de56d2d0bd39fc1751.svg";

Comment: I will file an issue for them thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite-loader`, now `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprites`. You're trying to use the extension with a sprite file, but actually, the plugin expects single SVG images — it'll generate the `sprites.svg` file from the SVG images you import on your project. Let's suppose that you have two files, `images/potato.svg` and `images/tomato.svg`. With this plugin — and I believe that `gatsby-plugin-svg-sprite` works the same way —, you must use them like in the following example:

```
import React from 'react'
import potato from 'images/potato.svg'
import tomato from 'images/tomato.svg'

export default () => (
  <>
    <svg viewBox={potato.viewBox}>
      <use xlinkHref={potato.url} />
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox={tomato.viewBox}>
      <use xlinkHref={tomato.url} />
    </svg>
  </>
)
```

The plugin will generate the `sprites.svg` file under the hood, so you don't have to worry about it. If you want to use a pre-built sprites file, there's no need to use a plugin. I believe you can use something like the following example:

```
import React from 'react'
import sprites from 'images/sprites.svg'

export default () => (
  <>
    <svg viewBox='...'>
      <use xlinkHref={`${sprites}#potato`} />
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox='...'>
      <use xlinkHref={`${sprites}#tomato`} />
    </svg>
  </>
)
```

You should set the `viewBox` property to the correct values of each sprite. Also, make sure that SVGO or any other SVG optimization plugin isn't removing symbols, ids or making any other change that could break your sprite file.